# XCode 6 beta 4 convenience init error

Tags: swift, xcode6, beta

It says `Could not find an overload for init that accepts the supplied arguments`

```
class MyController: UIViewController {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {    
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(nibName: "CreditOptionsView", bundle: nil)
    }

}
```

Why?
It was working in the XCode 6 beta 2

Comment: Cannot reproduce, compiles in Version 6.3 beta 4 (6D554n).

Comment: Always do a clean build when upgrading Xcode

Comment: I cleaned it (with `cmd+shift+alt+k`)

Comment: Yeah, as you said, I tried over an empty project and it worked, hmm

Comment: The problem would occur if you override a *designated* initialiser in your subclass (e.g. `required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`. Because then all convenience initializers are not inherited anymore.

Comment: :( they should, why I need to add an empty function... more boiler plate...

Answer (score 3):

I solve it writing an empty override of the function, I don't know why swift can't find it. ex:

```
class MyController: UIViewController {

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?){
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }       

    convenience init() {
        self.init(nibName: "CreditOptionsView", bundle: nil)
    }

}
```

Same thing happened in a convenience init for `UINavigationController` and solved adding again the empty `override`:

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(rootViewController: UIViewController())
    }
}
```